# how to move the datagridview record value column to another record column and then save it into the database in the vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, oledb

how to move the datagridview record value column to another record column and then save it into the database in the vb.net. What I mean as follows is move the record value from the column "CIU" to the column "CIUB" and move the record value from the column "DPR" to the column "DPRB" and below I attach the screenshot I want with yellow marking.
What is the best way to recommend?.I want to do it with the event button

```
 Dim Path As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory
    Dim cn As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Path & "; Extended Properties=dBase IV"
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
    Private Sub fillDataGridView1()
        Try
            Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM GSDTS WHERE QTY > 0"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNM", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        da.Fill(dt)
                        da.Dispose()
                        source1.DataSource = dt
                        'Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = source1
                        Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        fillDataGridView1()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            connectionString = cn
            con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            con.Open()
            Dim sql As String = "UPDATE GSDTS SET CIUB = CIU, CIU = NULL WHERE QTY > 0"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            Me.fillDataGridView1()
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        For Each row As DataRow In source1.Rows
            row("CIUB") = row("CIU")
            row("CIU") = DBNull.Value
        Next
    End Sub
```

thanks
jack
[image: ORIGINAL IN DATAGRIDVIEW]
[image: DESIRED RESULT IN DATAGRIDVIEW]

Comment: Firstly, there's no point using a `BindingSource` if you don't actually use it. The whole point is that it sits between the data source and the UI but you're binding the data source directly to the UI. Start by adding your `BindingSource` in the designer, so it can be accessed anywhere and its events handled. Then, after binding your `DataTable` to the `BindingSource`, you bind the `BindingSource` - not the `DataTable` - to the `DataGridView`.

Comment: There's no point disposing your data adapter. You're creating it with a `Using` statement so the whole point is that it gets disposed automatically. You can also create the connection, command and adapter with one `Using` statement, separated by commas. You only need to nest `Using` blocks if you need code in between. Finally, the command is pointless because you can just pass the query text and the connection to the data adapter constructor. In fact, you don't need the connection either because you can pass the query and the connection string.

Comment: @user18387401 , you can give an answer to my code that is wrong and I follow your best recommendations

Comment: @user18387401 , please guide me with answers from you so that I can learn from you

Comment: @user18387401 ,`after binding your DataTable to the BindingSource, you bind the BindingSource - not the DataTable - to the DataGridView.` for this point I have fixed and updated in my code

Comment: @user18387401 ,`There's no point disposing your data adapter. You're creating it with a Using statement so the whole point is that it gets disposed automatically. You can also create the connection, command and adapter with one Using statement, separated by commas. You only need to nest Using blocks if you need code in between.` for this point I don't understand whether you can give an example or answer

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing has nothing at all to do with the grid. That's for the user. You can just do it in the `BindingSource` or the `DataTable`. It's a simple loop:

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In myDataTable.Rows
    row("CIUB") = row("CIU")
    row("CIU") = DBNull.Value
    '...
Next
```

In fact, you don't even need to retrieve any data because you can do it all in SQL on the database:

```sql
UPDATE GSDTS
SET CIUB = CIU, CIU = NULL
WHERE QTY > 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. for your second answer about sql I've been in my code in button1 but in sql you are only for the column "CIU" & "CIUB" while for the column "DPR" & "DPRB". for your first answer I have an error 'Rows' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' how is the solution ?

Comment: @Jack, you need to familiarise yourself with the concept of an "example". It's a demonstration of a principle that you can then apply to other similar situations. I have provided an example that moves data from one column to another. Are you really saying that you can't see the principle that you can now apply to the another two columns?

Comment: @Jack, I told you that you can loop over a `BindingSource` or a `DataTable` and, again, I provided an example that uses a `DataTable`. It demonstrates a principle, i.e. looping over a collection. If you want to use a different collection then by all means do so. I shouldn't have to tell you how to do the same thing for every possible different collection.

Comment: `Are you really saying that you can't see the principle that you can now apply to the another two columns?`  I already understand

Comment: `I told you that you can loop over a BindingSource or a DataTable and, again, I provided an example that uses a DataTable` .for this question I how to save directly to the database if using the first answer ?

Comment: `There's no point disposing your data adapter. You're creating it with a Using statement so the whole point is that it gets disposed automatically. You can also create the connection, command and adapter with one Using statement, separated by commas. You only need to nest Using blocks if you need code in between`  for this point I don't understand whether you can give an example or answer

Comment: ,If you feel that you have an objection to giving a full answer according to the problem, it may be better that you do not need to give an answer. Because my simple problem will not make your time wasted a lot in providing solutions and answers if indeed you have a lot of experience